# Routing outbound traffic to mesh internal with istio

Tags: istio

In my setup I don't have istio gateway enabled. I am migrating services and application to K8S. Some of the services that this application talks to is within cluster which were previously reached via elb, changing the endpoint requires a downtime, hence wanted to route traffic that is destined to public endpoint directly to service endpoint within the cluster.

My setup is below.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: my-site-se
  namespace: site
spec:
  hosts:
  - my.example.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports: 
  - name: mytraffic
    number: 9009
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: NONE
```

My VirtualService definition.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my_site
  namespace: site
spec:
  hosts:
  - my.example.com
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 9009
    name: myapp-route    
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp.site.svc.cluster.local
```

Also application pod doesn't have istio enabled.

Comment: What do you mean "application pod doesn't have istio enabled."? You want to use Istio without essential Istio component?

Comment: The pod that run the app doesn't have istio sidecar enabled, while other application that connect  to it has istio sidecar enabled i.e istio-proxy.

Comment: Do you have any specific issue, or are you just looking for directions on how to set this up?

Comment: Request simple returns 503 from the envoy.
`* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

< server: envoy
< content-length: 0`